# Eclipse Link Unmarshalling null nested list from json restults in list with one null element

Tags: eclipselink

I have the following models:

```
     package com.ingenuity.app.kang.model
    
    import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
    import groovy.transform.ToString
    
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType
    
    @ToString(includeFields=true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @XmlType(name = "")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    @XmlRootElement
    class GabiData {
    
        @XmlElement
        Town town
    }
    package com.ingenuity.app.kang.model
    
    import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
    import groovy.transform.ToString
    
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType
    
    @XmlType(name = "")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    @ToString(includeFields = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    class Town {
    
        @XmlElement
        List<Person> persons
    }

package com.ingenuity.app.kang.model

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType

@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@ToString(includeFields = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Person {

    @XmlElement
    String address

    @XmlElement
    List<String> names
}
```

When I unmarshall the following json, GabiData will have a town with one person having names as [null].

```
{
  "gabiData": {
    "town": {
      "persons": [
        {
          "address": "Spain",
          "names": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening, is something wrong with my config or maybe a bug in Eclipse Link? I added these simple models as an example.
I use Eclipse Link 2.5.2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing vs what you are expecting to see - the data has a Person with null names list, so what you state seems like the correct unmarshalling behavior.